# Increasing cpu.shares cgroup granularity

Tags: cgroups

By default this value is set to 1024. I'm assuming that means that if I set the shares for my group to 1024, it'll be 100% of the available computing power.

Is there any way for me to increase the granularity for this? For example, rather than maxing out at 1024, I want to max out at 2048 or 8196.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, cpu.shares is already incredibly granular.

> cpu.shares: The weight of each group living in the same hierarchy, that
>    translates into the amount of CPU it is expected to get. Upon cgroup creation,
>    each group gets assigned a default of 1024. The percentage of CPU assigned to
>    the cgroup is the value of shares divided by the sum of all shares in all
>    cgroups in the same level.

The value of cpu.shares is used to compare to other cgroups.  If you have a single process running under cgroups, no matter the value of cpu.shares it will always get as much CPU as the host can spare.  Multiple processes running under cgroups assigned the same value for cpu.shares would split the available CPU evenly.

When you have multiple processes under cgroups, their cpu.shares values are compared together, and those with a higher number get a higher percent of the available host CPU.  If you have `cpu.shares=1024` for two cgrouped processes, then assign `cpu.shares=2048` for a third process, the first two processes would get equal amounts of the available CPU while the third would get twice as much of the available CPU (roughly 25%, 25%, 50%).

The actual numbers could be anything you want (now that's granular), only the percentage difference between them matters.  The results from the above example would be replicated if you used `cpu.shares=5` and `cpu.shares=10` or `cpu.shares=50000` and `cpu.shares=100000`

Comment: I thought this as well, but my testing shows otherwise.For 2 stress testing processes A and B, I have A in a cgroup with 128 shares and B not in a cgroup. A takes up ~10% of the processing power while ~90% goes to B. Any idea why this is?

Comment: The process not in a cgroup gets all the cpu the kernel can give it, no matter what your cgroup settings are, as it is not in a cgroup.  The process in the cgroup will get whatever leftover CPU is available, since it is the only cgroup process, it will recieve 100% of the CPU available to it (which in your example, is only 10% of the full CPU due to non cgroup processes taking the rest)

Comment: Further testing seems to not support what you're saying. A's CPU usage is proportional to the cpu.shares value of its cgroup. When I cut down CPU shares to 64, it drops to 5%. I move it up to 256 and it goes up to around 20%. I'm thinking that the value defined in /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpu.shares (1024) is some base value used by non-cgroup'd processes. Both A and B are instances of stress -- they should both be attempting to saturate the CPU as heavily as possible.

Comment: That seems to be correct. The default for non-cgroup'd processes is 1024 (or whatever that value is set to). Imagine proc A in group g1 with 2048 shares, B in group g2 with 1024 shares, and C in no cgroup (1024 default shares). A will get a min of 50%, B will get a min of 25%, and C will get a min of 25%. If you can update your answer to reflect this I can go ahead and mark it as correct.

Comment: You never state which kernel/distribution you are using, but it sounds like all of your processes are being run in cgroups.  If you are starting processes using systemd, then processes may be running in cgroups by default.  If that is not the case and you have the newest kernel, I may need to reread the documentation to see if anything changed, but in my previous experience processes not in cgroups are not limited in any way by cgroup settings.

Comment: I think you're correct in that this is a systemd gotcha :/ I'm using Mint 18. I'll mark your answer as correct. People will be able to follow this thread for the additional info.

Comment: I do not have Mint 18 in front of me, but I do have Ubuntu 16.04 which should be close.  The bash process for each logged in user runs under cgroups (due to systemd), so all your child processes would also be in cgroups.